# Evaluating Single Object against OData Query

Tags: c#, odata

I have an app written in C#. In that app, I'm serializing C# objects into JSON. At a later point in time, I want to see if a single object "matches" an OData $filter string. In other words, I want to use an OData $filter like a `Regex.Match`.

My question is, is there a way to do this? Everything that I've evaluated uses LINQ under the covers. This means that an `IQueryable` required. This means that I have to first add my C# object to some collection. This seems like a hack that adds overhead.

Is there a way to use an OData $filter the same way I can use the `Regex.Match` method? Thanks!

Comment: I think your quesiton is a bit ambiguous. By "I want to use an OData $filter like a Regex.Match", what do you mean? Your Odata $filter is a string, and Regex.Match is something else entirely.

Comment: @Philzax - A Regular Expression string let's you match against a pattern. A `$filter` string is a pattern in a certain light. You only see an item in a result set if it *matches* the `$filter` pattern. If the item does not match the `$filter` pattern, it is not included in the result set. My issue is, everything in the OData to Linq world requires a collection to begin with. I just want to run this test against a single object.  II don't believe it's ambiguous. Basically, I want to use a different pattern matching language. Instead of a regular expression string, I want to use an OData string.

Comment: So you'd just want to use the Odata $filter string as a pattern and check if it matches the serialized JSON string of one object?

Comment: @Philzax That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your responses to my comments, unless I am misunderstanding you.

You don't need to store your object in a IQueryable in order to this:

```
//your object, with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes
var yourObject = new YourObject();

//populate the properties or whatever you want with your object
yourObject.Blabla = 1;

//serialize your object into a string
var objectSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);

//your Regex string pattern, something like this?
var pattern = Odata.Filter;

//Use Regex to try to match the  pattern with the serialized object, no IQueryable needed
var match = Regex.Match(objectSerialized, pattern);

//See if the regex matched
if (match.Success)
    //do something
```